# An error was reported during the start of kylin

Tags: hive, kylin

My CDH version is `5.16.1`. Hive, hbase, spark, and yarn are all default versions. There is no manual upgrade. These components are functioning normally. The version of kylin I am using is `2.5`, with environment variables configured. Tested the environment with the "`check-env.sh -v`" script without any errors. Start with "`kylin.sh start`" script, the error message is:

```
ERROR: Check hive's usability failed, please check the status of your cluster
```

If anyone has encountered such an error, please give me some suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Check that your Hcatlog is installed